# Custom CSS shape with borders and background image

Tags: css, html, sass, css-transforms, clip-path

Hi guys im trying to do this in css/sass only! The border have to change on rollover and the background could be an image! I tried SVG and clipPath, transform3d without any success!Example here

[image]

Comment: Do you want it to work in all browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the workaround that we found. It will need some adjustement but look good for our need!

```
<a href="">
        <svg class="stroke-path" height="100%" width="100%">
            <defs>
                <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%">
                    <image xlink:href="http://cdn.collider.com/wp-content/uploads/super-mario-bros.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
                </pattern>
            </defs>
            <path id="mlp2" d="M206.5,173.1L33.3,162.5c-6.3,0-11.4-5.1-11.3-11.4c0,0,0,0,0,0L10.5,39.8c0-6.3,5.1-11.4,11.3-11.4 c0,0,0,0,0,0l208.2-17.9c6.3,0,11.4,5.1,11.3,11.4c0,0,0,0,0,0l-23.6,139.8C217.8,168,212.8,173.1,206.5,173.1 C206.5,173.1,206.5,173.1,206.5,173.1z" fill="url(#img1)" fill-opacity="1" />
        </svg>  
        <svg class="" height="100%" width="100%">
            <defs>
                <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0" width="200%" height="200%">
                    <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceGraphic" dx="0" dy="0" />
                    <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="8" />
```

-->

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXBPOz

Answer (score 0):

Create the container div and use transforms in CSS to give the entire element the 3d effect. You can look this up and play with the values to your liking.

Make the background image the background of the container div to keep it simple.

Use an SVG to draw the controller icon. There are some tutorials out there on how to export a path for an SVG using GIMP, at least that is what I do for complicated shapes like this.

Comment: No problems with the controlers icons... If I use css transform for the shape it distort the background image wich it's not looking nice! :(

Comment: So you want the border to have the 3d effect but not the background image?

Comment: Ive come with a solution I will post it here later! But it seems to work perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is best done like this, first the html structure:

```
<div id="imageContainer" class="center">
<h2>Lets go and see how it goes</h2>
<img class="pic" src="https://moltopiccolo.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/cool-      drinks.jpg"> 
</div>
```

This means, you have a container div and place your img in that container, it is important to not have the img as div background in this instance.

Second, position the div relative, the image absolute.This will only work if the image is positioned absolute.

Now declare a clip path, there are generators for different shapes with previews etc, check the codepen for the correct declarations.

Give a transition to the clip path, make sure to use the prefixes.

Now it is up to you wheter you want to trigger the animation on hover, this can be done with css. If you want the animations triggered on click, you can do that in JS and change the clip paths with JS.

I think the border animation needs no explanation, this is the very easiest part, if you need help with that, let me know.

Here is the link, hover over the picture and see:-)

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/KdobyK